# How to duplicate sales rule programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2, programmatically, rules

Im try to duplicate some salesrule exist, i can duplicate this, but i can't use **setConditionsSerialized** and **setActionsSerialized** with **getCondition** and **getActionCondition, its dont working**

```
    use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleRepository;
    use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory;

        protected $_ruleRepostitory;

        protected $_ruleFactory;

 public function __construct(
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        RuleRepository $ruleRepostitory,
) {
        $this->_ruleRepostitory = $ruleRepostitory;
        $this->_ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
}

                $id = 1;
                $getRule = $this->_ruleRepostitory->getById($id);
                $ruleModel = $this->_ruleFactory->create();
                $Default = 'ABCZXC';
                $randomNumber = random_int(000, 999);
                $ruleModel->setName($getRule->getName())
                    ->setDescription($getRule->getDescription())
                    ->setCouponType(2)
                    ->setConditionsSerialized(json_encode($getRule->getCondition()))
                    ->setActionsSerialized(json_encode($getRule->getActionCondition()))
                    ->setCouponCode($random = $Default . " - " . $randomNumber)
                    ->setFromDate($getRule->getFromDate())
                    ->setToDate($getRule->getFromDate())
                    ->setUsesPerCustomer($getRule->getUsesPerCustomer())
                    ->setCustomerGroupIds($getRule->getCustomerGroupIds())
                    ->setIsActive($getRule->getIsActive())
                    ->setStopRulesProcessing($getRule->getStopRulesProcessing())
                    ->setIsAdvanced($getRule->getIsAdvanced())
                    ->setProductIds($getRule->getProductIds())
                    ->setSortOrder($getRule->getSortOrder())
                    ->setSimpleAction($getRule->getSimpleAction())
                    ->setDiscountAmount($getRule->getDiscountAmount())
                    ->setDiscountQty($getRule->getDiscountQty())
                    ->setDiscountStep($getRule->getDiscountStep())
                    ->setSimpleFreeShipping($getRule->getSimpleFreeShipping())
                    ->setApplyToShipping($getRule->getApplyToShipping())
                    ->setTimesUsed($getRule->getTimesUsed())
                    ->setIsRss($getRule->getIsRss())
                    ->setWebsiteIds($getRule->getWebsiteIds())
                    ->setUsesPerCoupon($getRule->getUsesPerCoupon());
  $ruleModel->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah,  I did it, this is my code for duplicate Sales Rule . Does anyone have different answer .

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory;

protected $_ruleFactory;

public function __construct(
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory
)
{
        $this->_ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $duplicateRule = $this->_ruleFactory->create();
            $ruleModel = $this->_ruleFactory->create()->load($id);
            $default = 'ABCZXC'; // random code with ABCZXC+xxx, your can Enabled Use Auto Generation if you want
            print_r($ruleModel->getData());
            $randomNumber = random_int(000, 999);
            $duplicateRule
                ->setName($ruleModel->getName())
                ->setDescription($ruleModel->getDescription())
                ->setCouponType($ruleModel->getCouponType())
                ->setConditionsSerialized($ruleModel->getConditionsSerialized())
                ->setActionsSerialized($ruleModel->getActionsSerialized())
                ->setCouponCode($random = $default . " - " . $randomNumber)
                ->setFromDate($ruleModel->getFromDate())
                ->setToDate($ruleModel->getFromDate())
                ->setUsesPerCustomer($ruleModel->getUsesPerCustomer())
                ->setCustomerGroupIds($ruleModel->getCustomerGroupIds())
                ->setIsActive($ruleModel->getIsActive())
                ->setStopRulesProcessing($ruleModel->getStopRulesProcessing())
                ->setIsAdvanced($ruleModel->getIsAdvanced())
                ->setProductIds($ruleModel->getProductIds())
                ->setSortOrder($ruleModel->getSortOrder())
                ->setSimpleAction($ruleModel->getSimpleAction())
                ->setDiscountAmount($ruleModel->getDiscountAmount())
                ->setDiscountQty($ruleModel->getDiscountQty())
                ->setDiscountStep($ruleModel->getDiscountStep())
                ->setSimpleFreeShipping($ruleModel->getSimpleFreeShipping())
                ->setUseAutoGeneration($ruleModel->getUseAutoGeneration())
                ->setApplyToShipping($ruleModel->getApplyToShipping())
                ->setTimesUsed($ruleModel->getTimesUsed())
                ->setIsRss($ruleModel->getIsRss())
                ->setWebsiteIds($ruleModel->getWebsiteIds())
                ->setUsesPerCoupon($ruleModel->getUsesPerCoupon());
            $duplicateRule->save();
}
```